What's the deal with domains in execution?
P2300's execution has introduced execution domains such as std::execution::default_domain and the functions transform_env, transform_sender, and apply_sender.
I didn't see how these concepts play with the user-side. In other words, i can't find any examples using the domains except for the implementation details where the early and late domains terms are used in sender algorithms.
What are they exactly? How are they going to play a role as a customization for existing sender algorithms? Can I create my own execution domain?

Not a full explanation but has some details: https://ericniebler.com/2024/02/04/what-are-senders-good-for-anyway/

P2300R10, the paper that proposed std::execution, explains what domains are supposed to be used for:

Senders being able to advertise what their completion schedulers are fulfills one of the promises of senders: that of being able to customize an implementation of a sender algorithm based on what scheduler any work it depends on will complete on.
[...]
This means that well-meant specialization of sender algorithms that are entirely scheduler-agnostic can have negative consequences. The scheduler-specific specialization - which is essential for good performance on platforms providing specialized ways to launch certain sender algorithms - would not be selected in such cases. But it’s really the scheduler that should control the behavior of sender algorithms when a non-default implementation exists, not the sender. Senders merely describe work; schedulers, however, are the handle to the runtime that will eventually execute said work, and should thus have the final say in how the work is going to be executed.
Therefore, we are proposing the following customization scheme: the expression execution::<sender-algorithm>(sender, args...), for any given sender algorithm that accepts a sender as its first argument, should do the following:

Create a sender that implements the default implementation of the sender algorithm. That sender is tuple-like; it can be destructured into its constituent parts: algorithm tag, data, and child sender(s).
We query the child sender for its domain. A domain is a tag type associated with the scheduler that the child sender will complete on. If there are multiple child senders, we query all of them for their domains and require that they all be the same.
We use the domain to dispatch to a transform_sender customization, which accepts the sender and optionally performs a domain-specific transformation on it. This customization is expected to return a new sender, which will be returned from <sender-algorithm> in place of the original sender.


From the user point of view, you won't have to worry about domains unless you implement your own scheduler, and specifically for an execution resource that would benefit from some implementation of a sender algorithm other than the default one. In such cases, you declare your own domain, implement the method query for your scheduler type that takes a parameter of type get_domain_t so that it returns a value of that domain type, and implement the transform_sender method for your custom domain so that it accepts a sender whose tag is that of the algorithm you want to customize and returns the customized implementation.
